# CSS Div Transition between classes only happening one way

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Solution has been found.

I have a Javascript function that makes a div appear and then go away after a couple of seconds. However, I want the div to transition so that it's smooth and just doesn't reappear and disappear instantaneously. I've gotten it to work... partially. When the function is called, the div appears smoothly, but disappears without a transition. I've done a lot of troubleshooting without success and looked for a lot of solutions which have been no help.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="uiLog" class="ui_hidden">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ui = function () {
}

ui.log = function (message) {
 document.getElementById('uiLog').innerHTML += (message+"<br>");
 clearTimeout(uiTimeout);
 document.getElementById('uiLog').className = 'uiLog_shown';
  uiTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById('uiLog').className = 'ui_hidden';
     document.getElementById('uiLog').innerHTML = ("");
      }, 2000);
}
```

And finally, the CSS: (cut out unnecessary parts of it for easier viewing)

```
  .uiLog_shown {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    padding: 7px;
    border color: #271a0c;
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 15%;
  }

.ui_hidden {
 top: -500px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 position: absolute;
}
```

What I want:

- The function when called eases the div in slowly
- After the setTimeout runs its course the div eases out slowly

What doesn't and does work:

- The function when called eases the div in slowly
- After the setTimeout runs its course the div disappears instantly

So what is the problem? Why does it transition in but not out? Also, please no Jquery, just stick to JS and CSS.

Comment: damn i love js you are my ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote some class and animation, but the base not change:

```js
var ui = function () {};

var uiTimeout;

ui.log = function (message) {
    clearTimeout(uiTimeout);
    document.getElementById('uiLog').innerHTML = (message);
    document.getElementById('uiLog').className = 'ui_shown';
    uiTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('uiLog').className = 'ui_hidden';
    }, 2500);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    ui.log('Test')
}, 500);
```

```css
#uiLog {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 1em;
    padding: 7px;
    border-color: #271a0c;
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 15%;
    opacity: 0;
}

#uiLog.ui_shown {
    opacity: 1;
}

#uiLog.ui_hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="uiLog">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`transition: all .5s ease;` will only give you transition effect for in but for both in and you use `transition: all .5s ease-in-out;`

```
 .uiLog_shown {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    padding: 7px;
    border color: #271a0c;
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 15%;
  }

.ui_hidden {
 top: -500px;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Just did that but nothing has changed. It still eases in but will not ease out.

Comment: One minute, I'll have to change a few things for it to standalone.

Comment: Having some really weird troubles with the Fiddle so I'll try a different site.

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNEdxV). So it works now kind of, but it transitions out very weird, popping up in the left hand corner. Any idea how to make it transition from the direction it came?

Comment: I just added "right: 0px;" and it works now. Sorry for the hassle and thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah but do u knw why?? because you are changing the class and the properties in shown class is not more usable for hidden class so you can use method u used or good practice is to use common class for css and other classes for jquery work so that with classes styling will not get effected